# How to keep same line on terminal top with long output?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scroll

Under Ubuntu 14.04, I'm writing a script that output a lot of text (several commands...), and I would like to keep one or more lines always on top of the terminal screen to display what's running title.
In other words, I try to reduce terminal vertical scroll zone and write in that non-scrolling zone.

How can I do that? I saw similar stuff using a loop catching output line by line, but I'm unable to find a way to tell the system to print from let's say line 2 or 3.

Thanks for your answers,

Nicolas

Comment: Can you change the title of the window? Will that work for you?

Comment: Actually, that could do it, but I would prefer if possible the scroll zone reduction.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do used to be provided by using curses library, that gives you full control of the screen.  Have you looked at that?

Answer (score 2):

Nic,  it appears this does quite nicely.

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

Comment: I wrote something simple seems to do the job:  

`#!/bin/bash`
`# Clear the screen, move to (0,0):`
`echo -en "\[\033[2J\]"`
`# Erase to end of line:`
`#  \033[K`
`ls -al`
`# Save cursor position:`
`echo -en "\[\033[s\]"`
`echo -en "\[\033[2J\]"`
`# Restore cursor position:`
`echo -en "\[\033[u\]"`